# How to convert an Dom.XMLNode to its String representation in order to get CDATA content

Tags: xml

The context is that my ELEMENT node does not contain a TEXT node but a CDATA element as in the following:

```
<Root>
   <SomeNode>
      <![CDATA[Some message that i need to get]]>
   </SomeNode>
</Root>
```

In other words, I cannot use `node.getText()`.

The goal is to extract the message inside in the `<![CDATA[]]>` container. I read from other [posts](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000090f0IAA) that this can be done using XMLStreamReader but in order to do that I will still need a string data to initialise the XMLStreamReader with. Does anyone know a workaround to go about with this without having to rewrite the rest of the parsing code to use XMLStreamReader instead of Dom.XMLNode?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work around this issue using EncodingUtil. Before converting the HttpResponse to a Dom.XMLNode, I removed the CDATA encapsulation using String methods.

```
String xml = Http.send(request).getBody();

String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(xml,'UTF-8');
encoded = encoded.replaceAll('%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B',''); // i.e. '<![CDATA['
encoded = encoded.replaceAll('%5D%5D%3E',''); // i.e. ']]>'
xml = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encoded,'UTF-8');

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);
```

I used `replaceAll()` to remove the characters that encapsulate the CDATA message. I had to use url encoding since without it, the `<![CDATA[ Message inside ]]>` element is hidden from the `replaceAll()` method.

After this, I can now easily retrieve the message using the `getText()` on the Dom.XMLNode.

```
// <Root><SomeNode><![CDATA[Some message that i need to get]]></SomeNode></Root>
Dom.XMLNode node = doc.getRootElement();
String message = node.getChildElement('SomeNode', null).getText();

System.debug(message);    
// Output: Some message that i need to get
```

Answer (score 2):

I've approached this slightly differently. Inspired by [Martin Verdejo](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/35056/revisions)'s answer with replacing the `<![CDATA[]]>` sections, simply removing them still doesn't protect you from the purpose of having the CDATA tags to begin with: **nested content that itself contains XML tags.**

In my approach I use regular expression to match the CDATA sections then replace them with the **escaped xml** of the CDATA content. This attempts to preserve the protections of the CDATA tags and allow us to use Dom.XMLNode to retrieve the text of those elements.

## Escape XML content within CDATA tags then remove CDATA tags

```
String xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<root>' +
'  <SomeNode><![CDATA[<b>contains html tags</b>]]></SomeNode>' +
'</root>';

// replace CDATA sections with parseable tokens
xml = xml.replaceAll( '<!\\[CDATA\\[', 'XML_CDATA_START' ).replaceAll( ']]>', 'XML_CDATA_END' );

// we will build up a map of original text and replacement text
Map<String, String> replacementMap = new Map<String, String>();

// regular expression to match sections we want to replace
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile( '(XML_CDATA_START)(.*?)(XML_CDATA_END)' );
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher( xml );

while ( myMatcher.find() ) {
    // the regex was too complicated for Matcher.replaceFirst(..)
    // so have to do it manually so just put in this map the
    // original text and the replacement text, we do replacing later
    replacementMap.put( myMatcher.group(), myMatcher.group(2).escapeXML() );
}

// replace in the xml each CDATA section with the escaped XML of its inner content
for ( String key : replacementMap.keySet() ) {
    xml = xml.replace( key, replacementMap.get( key ) );
}

// parse the xml like normal
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load( xml );

Dom.XMLNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
String text = rootNode.getChildElement( 'SomeNode', null ).getText();
System.debug( text ); // prints: <b>contains html tags</b>
```

## Encode/Decode Fails if CDATA inner content contains XML tags

```
String xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<root>' +
'  <SomeNode><![CDATA[<b>contains html tags</b>]]></SomeNode>' +
'</root>';

// this does remove the CDATA tags but does not handle the inner content
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode( xml, 'UTF-8' );
encoded = encoded.replaceAll( '%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B', '' ); // i.e. '<![CDATA['
encoded = encoded.replaceAll( '%5D%5D%3E', '' ); // i.e. ']]>'
xml = EncodingUtil.urlDecode( encoded, 'UTF-8' );

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load( xml );

Dom.XMLNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
String text = rootNode.getChildElement( 'SomeNode', null ).getText();
System.debug( text ); // nothing prints because without CDATA tags 'SomeNode' has a child element <b>
```

## Vote on IdeaExchange

Please vote for this idea to be implemented natively: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000081cUAAQ

Answer (score -1):

Here's Apex code I wrote which removes CDATA and escapes any special characters in the text value which would blow up XML.

Apologies, I had to remove the code. To remove CDATA, you can scan the string for CDATA tokens and then use escapeXML() SF function to ensure your XML doesn't blow up.